# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer(): выгруженный .xls файл Excel (Windows 7) считает неправильным и не открывает

Tags: php, windows, excel

Генерирую и выгружаю .xls файл через старый класс Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer() следующим образом:

```
$xls = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$xls->setVersion(8);
$sheet = $xls->addWorksheet(iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251','list'));
$sheet->setInputEncoding('CP1251');
$sheet->write( 0, 0, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', 'Тест' ) );
$sheet->write( 1, 0, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', 'Тест2' ) );
$sheet->write( 2, 0, iconv( 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', 'test' ) );
$xls->send( 'test.xls' );
$xls->close();
```

Excel 2007 на Windows 7 отказывается открывать данный файл ("файл имеет неверный формат" или что-то такое), однако LibreOffice в Ubuntu открывает и отображает файл отлично, с нужной кодировкой даже. Пытался всячески менять кодировки, версии и прочее - не помогло.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer Excel 2007 Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066091/spreadsheet-excel-writer-excel-2007-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, может быть проблема в типе данных, которые Вы пытаетесь сохранить.

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [PHP XLSX Writer](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter). В установке простая и в пользовании тоже.

Вот небольшой пример того, как записать данные:

```
$data = array(
    array('year','month','amount'),
    array('2003','1','220'),
    array('2003','2','153.5'),
);

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$writer->writeSheet($data);
$writer->writeToFile('output.xlsx');
```